# Series convergence of function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]:\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined as:
$$f(x):=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}\sin\left(\frac{x}{n^2}\right)$$.
How do I go about showing $f$ converges? And how o show it is increasing $(0,\pi/2)$?

Comment: $\sin(x/(n^2))\le 1$

Comment: for increasing maybe you could take the derivative

Comment: @VladimirLenin Then use geometric series?

Comment: for convergence remember that we know $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}$ converges

Comment: To 1, correct? @VladimirLenin

Comment: yes I believe so

Comment: so for all $x$ in the domain, $f$ converges to a value less than or equal to 1

Answer (score 1):

You may probably know that $\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{1}{2^n}$ converges.  Now you use the fact, that $\sin(a) \leq 1$ for all $a$. This gives you a dominant convergent series, namely $\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{1}{2^n}$.

Also for $x < y \in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ you can show (or you just know), that for all $n$ as defined here $\sin(\frac{x}{n^2}) < \sin(\frac{y}{n^2})$. From this by pairwise comparison it follows, that the series $f(x) < f(y)$. If you have difficulties to understand this you might want to consider what happens when $x=0$ and $y = \frac{\pi}{2}$, and then ask yourself how the values change inside of the interval. Another point of view is just to see, that sine is monotone on the relevant interval.